# Auto update error messages

Tags: automatic-updates

I was having problems in the admin area with auto updates, keep getting error messages that say: Trying to get property of non-object in wordpress/wp-admin/update-core.php

I did a manual update to 5.2.4 and so expected the next auto update to be ok. Now 5.3 has been released, I'm still getting the same error message and the admin area states 5.2.4 is the latest version when it clearly isn't. Has anyone else had this and how can I rectify this please?

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: do you have this error only on URL `wp-admin/update-core.php` ? what is the complete error message ?

Comment: Hi Kaperto, thanks for replying to me. The entire message says this:                            Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/sumac/public_html/wordpress/wp-admin/update-core.php on line 40   but it's also repeated but on about 12 different lines. So Line 40, Line 42, Line 46 etc.

Comment: I look on WordPress 5.3 and there is nothing on line 40 : https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.3/src/wp-admin/update-core.php#L40

Comment: Hi Kaperto, my site is still on 5.2.4 as the 5.3 cannot be accessed automatically. The other lines with the error message (apart from line 40)  are Line 42, 46, 58, 12, 113, 122 and 130. I don't know why there isn't anything on line 40 in 5.3 and why my auto update is trying to find something that isn't there! What about the other lines, does missing line 40 affect the subsequent lines?

Comment: ok then the problem looks like you don't receive update information. but I don't understand how you can update wordpress if this variable is empty. it's difficult to help without knowing the content of all these variables which cause the errors.

Comment: Hi Kaperto, thank you. Not sure if this helps at all, but the 'update-core.php' says the following on line 40: if ( 'en_US' == $update->locale && 'en_US' == get_locale() ) { Whilst the 'admin.php' on line 40 says this: update_option( 'db_upgraded', false ); Then line 42 to 47 says this:  /**
  * Fires on the next page load after a successful DB upgrade.
  *
  * @since 2.8.0
  */
 do_action( 'after_db_upgrade' );